# Spring Boot - invalid path for indirect dependencies

Tags: maven, spring-boot

For some reason, I started to receive errors when I start my Spring Boot application.

```
    Ignoring Class-Path entry xmpcore-5.1.2.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/2.9.1/metadata-extractor-2.9.1.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/2.9.1/xmpcore-5.1.2.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry commons-logging-api-1.1.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/github/junrar/junrar/0.7/junrar-0.7.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/github/junrar/junrar/0.7/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry commons-vfs2-2.0.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/github/junrar/junrar/0.7/junrar-0.7.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/github/junrar/junrar/0.7/commons-vfs2-2.0.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry commons-logging-1.1.1.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/github/junrar/junrar/0.7/junrar-0.7.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/github/junrar/junrar/0.7/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry maven-scm-api-1.4.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/github/junrar/junrar/0.7/junrar-0.7.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/github/junrar/junrar/0.7/maven-scm-api-1.4.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry plexus-utils-1.5.6.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/github/junrar/junrar/0.7/junrar-0.7.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/github/junrar/junrar/0.7/plexus-utils-1.5.6.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry maven-scm-provider-svnexe-1.4.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/github/junrar/junrar/0.7/junrar-0.7.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/github/junrar/junrar/0.7/maven-scm-provider-svnexe-1.4.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry maven-scm-provider-svn-commons-1.4.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/github/junrar/junrar/0.7/junrar-0.7.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/github/junrar/junrar/0.7/maven-scm-provider-svn-commons-1.4.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry regexp-1.3.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/github/junrar/junrar/0.7/junrar-0.7.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/github/junrar/junrar/0.7/regexp-1.3.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry cdm-4.5.5.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/netcdf4-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/cdm-4.5.5.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry udunits-4.5.5.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/netcdf4-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/udunits-4.5.5.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry httpservices-4.5.5.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/netcdf4-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/httpservices-4.5.5.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry httpclient-4.2.6.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/netcdf4-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/httpclient-4.2.6.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry commons-logging-1.1.1.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/netcdf4-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry commons-codec-1.6.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/netcdf4-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/commons-codec-1.6.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry httpmime-4.2.6.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/netcdf4-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/httpmime-4.2.6.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry httpcore-4.2.5.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/netcdf4-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/httpcore-4.2.5.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/netcdf4-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry joda-time-2.2.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/netcdf4-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/joda-time-2.2.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry jdom2-2.0.4.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/netcdf4-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/jdom2-2.0.4.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry quartz-2.2.0.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/netcdf4-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/quartz-2.2.0.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/netcdf4-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/netcdf4-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry ehcache-core-2.6.2.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/netcdf4-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/ehcache-core-2.6.2.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry guava-17.0.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/netcdf4-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/guava-17.0.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry bzip2-0.9.1.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/netcdf4-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/bzip2-0.9.1.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry jcommander-1.35.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/netcdf4-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/jcommander-1.35.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry jcip-annotations-1.0.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/netcdf4-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/jcip-annotations-1.0.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry jna-4.1.0.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/netcdf4-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/jna-4.1.0.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/netcdf4-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf4/4.5.5/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry cdm-4.5.5.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/grib-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/cdm-4.5.5.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry udunits-4.5.5.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/grib-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/udunits-4.5.5.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry httpservices-4.5.5.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/grib-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/httpservices-4.5.5.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry httpclient-4.2.6.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/grib-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/httpclient-4.2.6.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry commons-logging-1.1.1.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/grib-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry commons-codec-1.6.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/grib-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/commons-codec-1.6.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry httpmime-4.2.6.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/grib-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/httpmime-4.2.6.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry httpcore-4.2.5.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/grib-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/httpcore-4.2.5.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/grib-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry joda-time-2.2.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/grib-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/joda-time-2.2.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry quartz-2.2.0.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/grib-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/quartz-2.2.0.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/grib-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry ehcache-core-2.6.2.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/grib-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/ehcache-core-2.6.2.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry guava-17.0.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/grib-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/guava-17.0.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry jcommander-1.35.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/grib-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/jcommander-1.35.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/grib-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry jdom2-2.0.4.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/grib-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/jdom2-2.0.4.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry jsoup-1.7.2.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/grib-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/jsoup-1.7.2.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/grib-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry jcip-annotations-1.0.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/grib-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/jcip-annotations-1.0.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry jj2000-5.2.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/grib-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/jj2000-5.2.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry bzip2-0.9.1.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/grib-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/grib/4.5.5/bzip2-0.9.1.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry udunits-4.5.5.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/cdm-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/udunits-4.5.5.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry httpservices-4.5.5.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/cdm-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/httpservices-4.5.5.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry httpclient-4.2.6.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/cdm-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/httpclient-4.2.6.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry commons-logging-1.1.1.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/cdm-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry commons-codec-1.6.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/cdm-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/commons-codec-1.6.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry httpmime-4.2.6.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/cdm-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/httpmime-4.2.6.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry httpcore-4.2.5.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/cdm-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/httpcore-4.2.5.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/cdm-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry joda-time-2.2.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/cdm-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/joda-time-2.2.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/cdm-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry jdom2-2.0.4.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/cdm-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/jdom2-2.0.4.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry jcip-annotations-1.0.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/cdm-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/jcip-annotations-1.0.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry quartz-2.2.0.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/cdm-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/quartz-2.2.0.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/cdm-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/cdm-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry ehcache-core-2.6.2.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/cdm-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/ehcache-core-2.6.2.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry guava-17.0.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/cdm-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/guava-17.0.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry bzip2-0.9.1.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/cdm-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/bzip2-0.9.1.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry jcommander-1.35.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/cdm-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm/4.5.5/jcommander-1.35.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry joda-time-2.2.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/udunits/4.5.5/udunits-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/udunits/4.5.5/joda-time-2.2.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry jcip-annotations-1.0.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/udunits/4.5.5/udunits-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/udunits/4.5.5/jcip-annotations-1.0.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry mchange-commons-java-0.2.11.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/mchange/c3p0/0.9.5.2/c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/mchange/c3p0/0.9.5.2/mchange-commons-java-0.2.11.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry jcip-annotations-1.0.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/httpservices/4.5.5/httpservices-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/httpservices/4.5.5/jcip-annotations-1.0.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry httpclient-4.2.6.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/httpservices/4.5.5/httpservices-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/httpservices/4.5.5/httpclient-4.2.6.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry commons-logging-1.1.1.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/httpservices/4.5.5/httpservices-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/httpservices/4.5.5/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry commons-codec-1.6.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/httpservices/4.5.5/httpservices-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/httpservices/4.5.5/commons-codec-1.6.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry httpcore-4.2.5.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/httpservices/4.5.5/httpservices-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/httpservices/4.5.5/httpcore-4.2.5.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry httpmime-4.2.6.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/httpservices/4.5.5/httpservices-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/httpservices/4.5.5/httpmime-4.2.6.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/httpservices/4.5.5/httpservices-4.5.5.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/httpservices/4.5.5/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry geoapi-3.0.0.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/apache/sis/core/sis-utility/0.6/sis-utility-0.6.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/apache/sis/core/sis-utility/0.6/geoapi-3.0.0.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry jsr-275-0.9.3.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/apache/sis/core/sis-utility/0.6/sis-utility-0.6.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/apache/sis/core/sis-utility/0.6/jsr-275-0.9.3.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry sis-storage-0.6.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/apache/sis/storage/sis-netcdf/0.6/sis-netcdf-0.6.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/apache/sis/storage/sis-netcdf/0.6/sis-storage-0.6.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry sis-metadata-0.6.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/apache/sis/storage/sis-netcdf/0.6/sis-netcdf-0.6.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/apache/sis/storage/sis-netcdf/0.6/sis-metadata-0.6.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry sis-utility-0.6.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/apache/sis/storage/sis-netcdf/0.6/sis-netcdf-0.6.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/apache/sis/storage/sis-netcdf/0.6/sis-utility-0.6.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry sis-referencing-0.6.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/apache/sis/storage/sis-netcdf/0.6/sis-netcdf-0.6.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/apache/sis/storage/sis-netcdf/0.6/sis-referencing-0.6.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry geoapi-3.0.0.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/apache/sis/storage/sis-netcdf/0.6/sis-netcdf-0.6.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/apache/sis/storage/sis-netcdf/0.6/geoapi-3.0.0.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry jsr-275-0.9.3.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/apache/sis/storage/sis-netcdf/0.6/sis-netcdf-0.6.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/apache/sis/storage/sis-netcdf/0.6/jsr-275-0.9.3.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry sis-utility-0.6.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/apache/sis/storage/sis-storage/0.6/sis-storage-0.6.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/apache/sis/storage/sis-storage/0.6/sis-utility-0.6.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry sis-metadata-0.6.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/apache/sis/storage/sis-storage/0.6/sis-storage-0.6.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/apache/sis/storage/sis-storage/0.6/sis-metadata-0.6.jar does not exist
    Ignoring Class-Path entry sis-referencing-0.6.jar found in/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/apache/sis/storage/sis-storage/0.6/sis-storage-0.6.jar as /home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/apache/sis/storage/sis-storage/0.6/sis-referencing-0.6.jar does not exist
[...]
/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/opengis/geoapi/3.0.0/jsr-275-0.9.3.jar does not exist
    Spring boot app main
```

Command that starts the apllication:

```
/home/share/jdk8/bin/java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=34227 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /winshared/workspaces/sts/spring-ui/target/classes:/winshared/workspaces/sts/spring-ui/lib/cumulus.jar:/winshared/workspaces/sts/spring-ui/lib/poolman-4.0.jar:/winshared/workspaces/sts/spring-ui/lib/haerion.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-starter-actuator-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-starter-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-starter-logging-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.2.3/logback-core-1.2.3.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.25/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.18/snakeyaml-1.18.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-actuator-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.9.0.pr3/jackson-databind-2.9.0.pr3.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.9.0.pr3/jackson-annotations-2.9.0.pr3.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator-docs/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-actuator-docs-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/hateoas/spring-hateoas/0.23.0.RELEASE/spring-hateoas-0.23.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-core-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-jcl-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-starter-aop-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-aop-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.10/aspectjweaver-1.8.10.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-cache/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-starter-cache-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-context-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-expression-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context-support/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-context-support-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-freemarker/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-starter-freemarker-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/freemarker/freemarker/2.3.26-incubating/freemarker-2.3.26-incubating.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-mobile/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-starter-mobile-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/mobile/spring-mobile-device/2.0.0.M1/spring-mobile-device-2.0.0.M1.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-security/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-starter-security-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-security-config-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-security-core-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-security-web-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring5/3.0.6.M4/thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.6.M4.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/3.0.6.RELEASE/thymeleaf-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/attoparser/attoparser/2.0.4.RELEASE/attoparser-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/unbescape/unbescape/1.1.4.RELEASE/unbescape-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/extras/thymeleaf-extras-java8time/3.0.0.RELEASE/thymeleaf-extras-java8time-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-starter-validation-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.5.15/tomcat-embed-el-8.5.15.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.4.1.Final/hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.1.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.1.Final.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.3.3/classmate-1.3.3.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-starter-web-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-json/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-starter-json-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.9.0.pr3/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.0.pr3.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.9.0.pr3/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.0.pr3.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.5.15/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.5.15/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.15.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-web-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-webmvc-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-devtools/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-devtools-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.16.16/lombok-1.16.16.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/22.0/guava-22.0.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.0.18/error_prone_annotations-2.0.18.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/google/j2objc/j2objc-annotations/1.1/j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/animal-sniffer-annotations/1.14/animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/ognl/ognl/3.1.12/ognl-3.1.12.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.21.0-GA/javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/slieb/html-exception-formatter/1.3/html-exception-formatter-1.3.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/slieb/throwable-interfaces/1.10/throwable-interfaces-1.10.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/j2html/j2html/0.88/j2html-0.88.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/github/httl/httl/1.0.11/httl-1.0.11.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/h2database/h2/1.4.195/h2-1.4.195.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-configuration-processor/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-configuration-processor-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/external/google/android-json/0.0.20131108.vaadin1/android-json-0.0.20131108.vaadin1.jar:/home/dsu/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.13/commons-compress-.... p --spring.output.ansi.enabled=always
```

Answer (score 1):

I seems that this was added to boot-devtools [ChangeableUrls.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/47de05b52c0236a1a836e5f8ad6b3b3533d3fc03#diff-cc5107b50460aa1de079d2fee3c3ae2a) recently.

In your case the grib-4.5.5.jar will have a Class-Path definition in its MANIFEST.MF. 
The warning says that these jars mentioned in this Class-Path are not used, because they are not found relative to your grib-4.5.5.jar.